# How to create an immutable class

Tags: java

I want to make the class below immutable. Can anyone provide a simple example of creating an immutable class in java?

```
class Emp implements Comparable
{
      String name,job;
      int salary;
      public Emp(String n,String j,int sal)
      {
         name=n;
         job=j;
         salary=sal;
       }
      public void display()
      {
        System.out.println(name+"\t"+job+"\t"+salary);
       }
     public boolean equals(Object o)
      {

        // use a shortcut comparison for slightly better performance; not really required  
            if (this == o)  
            {  
                return true;   
            }  
            // make sure o can be cast to this class  
            if (o == null || o.getClass() != getClass())  
            {  
                // cannot cast  
                return false;  
            }            
            // can now safely cast       
          Emp p=(Emp)o;
          return this.name.equals(p.name)&&this.job.equals(p.job) &&this.salary==p.salary;
       }
      public int hashCode()
       {
          return name.hashCode()+job.hashCode()+salary;
       }


       public int compareTo(Object o)
       {
          Emp e=(Emp)o;
          return this.name.compareTo(e.name);
           //return this.job.compareTo(e.job);
        //   return this.salary-e.salary;

        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should read [this article on immutable objects](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29) instead.

Comment: just don't make public modifier methods (i.e. no `set` methods).

Answer (score 3):

Just label all fields of your class as `final`, and don't assign to them anywhere but the constructor for your class.

Comment: Preferably, the fields should be `private` as well, but all of the fields in the OP's example are of immutable types.

Comment: Yeah, fields should be either `private` or if they're immutable objects, `final`.

Answer (score 2):

Also, it's good to make the class final, or to only provide private constructors, and static factory methods.  This means people cannot subclass your class and override you methods.

for example:

```
public class Immutable {
    private final String value;
    private Immutable(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public static Immutable create(String value) { return new Immutable(value); }
    public String getValue() { return value; }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot, in this example if i declare the class as final too with your changes including static factory method that will make it 100% immutable..!! but please explain what the static factory method create is doing here..!!